# can I give a jQuery variable a class then change the font colour of that class

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

So when I append that certain variable which will always be one word but in a string with other words, it will be a different colour.

but searching for ways to do this for the last 5 hours... :(

coffee file

```
    App.room = App.cable.subscriptions.create "RoomChannel",
      connected: ->
        # Called when the subscription is ready for use on the server

      disconnected: ->
        # Called when the subscription has been terminated by the server

      received: (data) ->
        $('#messages').append data['message']


      speak: (message) ->
        @perform 'speak', message: message



    $(document).on 'keypress', '[data-behavior~=room_speaker]', (event) ->
      if event.keyCode is 13 # return/enter = send
        App.room.speak(name + ":"  + event.target.value )
        event.target.value = ''
        event.preventDefault()
```

Js file

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $("#user_button").on('click', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        name = $("#username").val()
        $('#chat-input').show();
        $('#chat-username').hide();
      });
```

I want name variable to be a different colour.

Comment: Show us your code please

Comment: Can you give an example? I don't realy understand what you are trying to do.

Comment: The answer is yes you can

Comment: `"I want name variable to be a different colour."` - *What?*  The `name` variable is going to contain exactly what you set it to contain, `$("#username").val()`.  (Well, once you correct your typo and put a semi-colon at the end of that statement.)  But then you don't *use* `name` for anything.  It's not clear to me what the problem is that you're trying to describe.

Comment: App.room.speak(name + ":"  + event.target.value ),     <- I use name right here

Comment: Ok Dave, pretend you know nothing about what you are doing and read your question - it is very unclear what you are trying to do

Comment: Ok, when I append the variable 'name' to the div, the font colour will be different... just for the word stored in the variable.

Comment: does your speak function just append the html to the DOM?  If so you can just wrap your variable in a span when you "speak" it: `'<span class="colour">' + name + '</span>'`

Comment: doing this actually prints out '<span class="colour">' + name + '</span>' this to message board?

Comment: @Dave name is contained in data['message']  like this  ' Dave:hi there '  or it is contained in other['name']  ???

Comment: hi Krishnar its contained in data['message']

Comment: Then what is in other['name'] ?

Comment: nothing now I've got of that section, I was playing around trying to get It to work.

Answer (score 1):

**Case1: If you have username contained in other['name'] then do like below**

```
received: (data) ->
  $('#messages').append data['message'],'<span style=\'color:red\'>' + other['name'] + '</span>'
```

**Case2: If its contained in Message then store with style**

```
  name_with_color = '<span style=\'color:red\'>' + name + '</span>'
  App.room.speak(name_with_color + ":"  + event.target.value )
```

Comment: Using case2: unfortunately this prints '<span style='color:red'>hey</span>:' out to the message board.